# How to custom 'format' an int in ASP.NET MVC Core?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have a primary key AccountNumber which is INT.
I want it to be displayed in my View like this: 123-456-78. How can I add '-' character between the numbers?

Thanks!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/formatting-types#custom-format-strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put in your view this code

```
<div> @Model.AccountNumber.ToString("000-000-00")  </div>
```